# How do you add an icon to link_to_unless_current using haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Is there a way to add an icon to the following link_to_unless_current? I need it to be added in both current and non-current states.

```
= link_to_unless_current("Stats", stats_practice_path(current_user.practice)) do content_tag(:div, content_tag(:p, "Stats"), :class => "nav-active") end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use a helper method for this.

Ex:

```
module ApplicationHelper

   def icon(image = "youricon.png")
     raw(image_tag(image)) 
   end

end
```

and in your view:

```
= link_to_unless_current(icon, stats_practice_path(current_user.practice)) do content_tag(:div, content_tag(:p, "Stats"), :class => "nav-active") end
```

(Note: I didn't test this myself, I think it should work :))

Comment: I added a custom helper method not any close to your but you inspired me.

Comment: glad to help, and if you could post your helper methods, I might learn something valuable :)